# Unable to reliably select element regardless of method using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the "Majors" button on [this webpage] (https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/)

I am able to switch into the iframe where this element is contained, but trying to click by using the xpath, id or class name of the element all result in a seemingly random button within the same column being selected. Below is the current code I'm using along with a screenshot of inspection of the button.

```
majorforexbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[4]')
majorforexbutton.click()
```

screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=':5x']").click() Try this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element with text as *Majors* field is within a `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src*='freeserv.dukascopy.com/2.0/?path=historical_data_feed']")))
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Instrument']"))))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-group='FX_MAJORS'][data-parent='FX']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src, 'freeserv.dukascopy.com/2.0/?path=historical_data_feed')]")))
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Instrument']"))))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='Majors']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Major]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: Did you try to click Major button manually on page ?? Please try to click it manually and see the difference . Actually your **output is wrong** as it has not clicked Major button instead it has clicked Austria under Stock (CFD) section.

Comment: @rahulrai Good observation. Check out the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Yeah, can see from attached output major is selected. Thanks!!

Comment: @EliBain Feel free to visit [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) and help other users.

Answer (score 0):

Try grabbing your element and trying either one of the bottom.

```
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, ":5x")))
```

1 of these:

```
elem.click()

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```